# When black holes rotating in opposite directions meet does frame dragging stop where they meet?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, event-horizon, frame-dragging

Does spacetime stop being dragged when  counterclockwise rotation meets clockwise rotation for black holes of equal mass?

Comment: Define 'meet' .

Answer (score 0):

After they merged the frame dragging will be neutralized since there is no preferred direction of rotation if both spins were equal and opposite, then the angular momentum will be converted to linear momentum known as "black hole kick" but in the moment they meet and are not yet merged the frame dragging will be strong.